# Same user name and notifications

Tags: support, user-accounts

My user name is 111 (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/100311/111)
but there is another person with this user name (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/382126/111). I noticed that, because someone replying in a chatroom to the other 111 user, sent me a message in my inbox!

Comment: Yes, usernames are not unique. Count for example how many (registered) users called "Frank" or "Thomas" we have.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for the reply. So, I will accept in my inbox all the replies for the other user?

Comment: No, that happens relatively rarely. For comments on the site, you two must both have commented on a post (or one of you have written or edited the post) for that to occur. Otherwise, the software knows which of you is meant by `@111`. In chat, it happens if both of you were active in the room in question not too long ago. Then the software doesn't know whom `@111` refers to, and pings you both, iirc.

Comment: ok, understood. Thanks.

Comment: The case of comment replies and users with the same username is discussed here: [Who should be pinged by the “@<user>” feature if there is more than one match](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/23330).

Comment: And I will add that in chat multiple users can receive ping even if they do not have exactly the same name. For example, if I and other user with username MartinR were in the same chatroom, writing @Martin in chat would ping both of us.

Comment: Maybe you could change your username to 3x37?

Comment: yes! or 9^2+3^3+3